# I got the warning mentioned in the title and my code is here:Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in

Tags: php, mysqli

I got the warning mentioned in the title and my code is here:Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be MySQLi, string given in 
/CDC/slider.php on line 3

slider.php

```
<?php require_once('db/dbcon.php'); ?>

<?php mysqli_select_db($database_dbcon, $dbcon);
$query_slide ="SELECT * FROM photos_slide_tb";
$slide  = mysqli_query($query_slide , $dbcon) or die(mysqli_error());
$row_slide = mysqli_fetch_assoc($slide );
$totalRows_slide  = mysqli_num_rows($slide ); ?>

    <div id="sliderFrame">
        <div id="slider">
        <?php if ($totalRows_slide == 0) { ?><h1>&nbsp;</h1>
            <h1 align="center">Not available</h1>

        <?php } else do { ?> 
            <img src="photos/<?php echo $row_slide['location'];?>"  alt="<?php echo $row_slide['caption'];?>" />
        <?php } while ($row_slide = mysqli_fetch_assoc($slide)); ?>
        </div>

        <div id="htmlcaption" style="display: none;">
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

dbcon.php

```
<?php
$hostname_dbcon = "localhost";
$database_dbcon = "123";
$username_dbcon = "123";
$password_dbcon = "123";
$dbcon = mysqli_connect($hostname_dbcon, $username_dbcon, $password_dbcon) or trigger_error(mysqli_error(), E_USER_ERROR); 
?>
```

Comment: Switch the variables `mysqli_select_db($dbcon, $database_dbcon);`

Comment: interchange your $params, connection has to go first before selecting a database.

Answer (score 0):

Correct params order is `$connection, $db_name`:

```
mysqli_select_db($dbcon, $database_dbcon);
```

Comment: another warning appear on line 5 Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /CDC/slider.php on line 5

Comment: @ElPresidente: the same, first param has to be connectin link, the second SQL query. `mysqli_query($dbcon, $query_slide)`.

Answer (score 0):

Passing wrong parameters. The first parameter is the `connection object` & the second parameter is the `database` name.

```
mysqli_select_db($dbcon, "Datebase Name");
```

Do the same for `mysqli_query()`

```
mysqli_query($dbcon, $query_slide);
```

Comment: another warning appear on line 5 Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /CDC/slider.php on line 5

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094244/log-in-page-looks-like-not-redirecting-to-the-next-page-how-do-i-fix-this/30094306#30094306

Answer (score 0):

You have placed arguments to mysqli_select_db() incorrectly.

Corrected one is:

```
mysqli_select_db($dbcon, $database_dbcon);
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

Comment: another warning appear on line 5 Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string given in /CDC/slider.php on line 5

Answer (score 0):

Correct params over both function

```
mysqli_select_db($database_dbcon, $dbcon);
```

should be

```
mysqli_select_db($dbcon,$database_dbcon);
```

and another

```
mysqli_query($query_slide , $dbcon)
```

should be

```
mysqli_query($dbcon, $query_slide)
```

Comment: i have an error again on my page can you help me fixing this?

Comment: But which one..Post your question

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094244/log-in-page-looks-like-not-redirecting-to-the-next-page-how-do-i-fix-this/30094306#30094306